# Shopping Cart view, change quantity widget to select box

Tags: views, commerce, forms

I have two kinds of price type: price per unit and price per weight. I have managed to use `hook_form_alter()` to change the widget textbox to a predefined select list.

For some items it fills the selectbox with '1 piece + price', '2 pieces + price'; for other items, I use '100 grams + price', '200grams + price' and so on. The code I have used for this is below.

```
function kmsol_quantity_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    //add to cart form
    if (strpos($form_id, 'commerce_cart_add_to_cart_form_') === 0) {
        // Replace the text quantity field with a select list.
        if (isset($form['quantity']) && ($form['quantity']['#type'] == 'textfield')) {

            $product = commerce_product_load($form['product_id']['#value']);
            $price   = commerce_product_calculate_sell_price($product);

            $prd_wrapper      = entity_metadata_wrapper('commerce_product', $form['product_id']['#value']);
            $field_price_type = $prd_wrapper->field_prijs_type->value();

            $weight_array = array(
                '0.1' => '100 gram ' . commerce_currency_format(0.1 * $price['amount'], $price['currency_code'], $product),
                '0.2' => '200 gram ' . commerce_currency_format(0.2 * $price['amount'], $price['currency_code'], $product),
                '0.3' => '300 gram ' . commerce_currency_format(0.3 * $price['amount'], $price['currency_code'], $product),
                '0.4' => '400 gram ' . commerce_currency_format(0.4 * $price['amount'], $price['currency_code'], $product),
                '0.5' => '500 gram ' . commerce_currency_format(0.5 * $price['amount'], $price['currency_code'], $product),
                '0.6' => '600 gram ' . commerce_currency_format(0.6 * $price['amount'], $price['currency_code'], $product),
                '0.7' => '700 gram ' . commerce_currency_format(0.7 * $price['amount'], $price['currency_code'], $product),
                '0.8' => '800 gram ' . commerce_currency_format(0.8 * $price['amount'], $price['currency_code'], $product),
                '0.9' => '900 gram ' . commerce_currency_format(0.9 * $price['amount'], $price['currency_code'], $product),
                '1' => '1 KG  ' . commerce_currency_format(1 * $price['amount'], $price['currency_code'], $product)
            );
            $piece_array  = array(
                '0.1' => '1 stuks ' . commerce_currency_format(1 * $price['amount'], $price['currency_code'], $product),
                '0.2' => '2 stuks ' . commerce_currency_format(2 * $price['amount'], $price['currency_code'], $product),
                '0.3' => '3 stuks ' . commerce_currency_format(3 * $price['amount'], $price['currency_code'], $product),
                '0.4' => '4 stuks ' . commerce_currency_format(4 * $price['amount'], $price['currency_code'], $product),
                '0.5' => '5 stuks ' . commerce_currency_format(5 * $price['amount'], $price['currency_code'], $product),
                '0.6' => '6 stuks ' . commerce_currency_format(6 * $price['amount'], $price['currency_code'], $product),
                '0.7' => '7 stuks ' . commerce_currency_format(7 * $price['amount'], $price['currency_code'], $product),
                '0.8' => '8 stuks ' . commerce_currency_format(8 * $price['amount'], $price['currency_code'], $product),
                '0.9' => '9 stuks ' . commerce_currency_format(9 * $price['amount'], $price['currency_code'], $product),
                '1' => '10 stuks ' . commerce_currency_format(10 * $price['amount'], $price['currency_code'], $product)
            );


            if ($field_price_type == 'Prijs per kilo') {
                $select = $weight_array;
            }
            if ($field_price_type == 'Prijs per stuk') {
                $select = $piece_array;
            }

            $form['quantity']['#type']    = 'select';
            $form['quantity']['#options'] = $select;
            $form['quantity']['#size']    = 1;
        }
    }
```

I want to do the same thing more or less on the *Shopping Cart* page. However, this is a view and therefore my code is not working over there.

I have tried some code but its not working at all, and I think I'm looking at it the wrong way.

This is what I have for the moment.

```
function kmsol_customcart_commerce_cart_order_load($uid = 0) 
{
    global $user;
    $order = commerce_cart_order_load($user->uid);
    dpm($uid);

        $order_wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('commerce_order', $order);

        foreach ($order_wrapper->commerce_line_items as $line_item => $line_item_wrapper) 
        {
            $product = $line_item_wrapper->commerce_product->value();
            $field_price_type = $product->field_prijs_type->value();
            dpm($field_price_type);
            $weight_array = array(
                '0.1' => '100 gram ' ,
                '0.2' => '200 gram ' ,
                '0.3' => '300 gram ' ,
                '0.4' => '400 gram ' ,
                '0.5' => '500 gram ' ,
                '0.6' => '600 gram ' ,
                '0.7' => '700 gram ' ,
                '0.8' => '800 gram ' ,
                '0.9' => '900 gram ' ,
                '1' => '1 KG  '
            );
            $piece_array  = array(
                '0.1' => '1 stuks ' ,
                '0.2' => '2 stuks ' ,
                '0.3' => '3 stuks ' ,
                '0.4' => '4 stuks ' ,
                '0.5' => '5 stuks ' ,
                '0.6' => '6 stuks ' ,
                '0.7' => '7 stuks ' ,
                '0.8' => '8 stuks ' ,
                '0.9' => '9 stuks ' ,
                '1' => '10 stuks ' 
            );          

            if ($field_price_type == 'Prijs per kilo') {    $select = $weight_array;    }
            if ($field_price_type == 'Prijs per stuk') {    $select = $piece_array;     }

            $form['edit_quantity']['#type']    = 'select';
            $form['edit_quantity']['#options'] = $select;
            $form['edit_quantity']['#size']    = 1;
        }
 }
```

The issue is that the quantity widget will be filled based upon the product type, so grams will remain grams and units stay units.

Comment: What are you trying to do ?

Comment: Well I have a products with 2 kind of prices, price per unit and price per weight. I have a field (field_prijs_type) which is a radio button. So when I add a product to the webshop, my quantity textbox becomes a drop down. The if thing is not working because tje syntax is wrong I guess.. Is this clear?

Comment: Better to add such details in your question (edit it and be as detailed as possible), then request moderators to reopen the question. 
As for a push in the right direction. Drupal radio options (as any other option on a multi-value field have a system name and a user friendly name). You should be looking for the system name. Further $form_state['values'] is only available after form submission or after an AJAX callback. I see neither of those in your code so it is probably not (yet) defined.

Comment: I have changed my opening post to be more clear now. My first issue is resolved meanwhile, I'm only having issues with the cart view. Would you reconsider opening this topic? @kiamlaluno thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution So i'll share it if someone else needs it..

---

```
hook_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id)
{//add to cart form
if (strpos($form_id, 'commerce_cart_add_to_cart_form_') === 0) {
    // Replace the text quantity field with a select list.
    if (isset($form['quantity']) && ($form['quantity']['#type'] == 'textfield')) {

        $product = commerce_product_load($form['product_id']['#value']);
        $price   = commerce_product_calculate_sell_price($product);

        $prd_wrapper      = entity_metadata_wrapper('commerce_product', $form['product_id']['#value']);
        $field_price_type = $prd_wrapper->field_prijs_type->value();

        $weight_array = array(
            '0.1' => '100 gram ' . commerce_currency_format(0.1 * $price['amount'], $price['currency_code'], $product),
            '0.2' => '200 gram ' . commerce_currency_format(0.2 * $price['amount'], $price['currency_code'], $product),
            '0.3' => '300 gram ' . commerce_currency_format(0.3 * $price['amount'], $price['currency_code'], $product),
            '0.4' => '400 gram ' . commerce_currency_format(0.4 * $price['amount'], $price['currency_code'], $product),
            '0.5' => '500 gram ' . commerce_currency_format(0.5 * $price['amount'], $price['currency_code'], $product),
            '0.6' => '600 gram ' . commerce_currency_format(0.6 * $price['amount'], $price['currency_code'], $product),
            '0.7' => '700 gram ' . commerce_currency_format(0.7 * $price['amount'], $price['currency_code'], $product),
            '0.8' => '800 gram ' . commerce_currency_format(0.8 * $price['amount'], $price['currency_code'], $product),
            '0.9' => '900 gram ' . commerce_currency_format(0.9 * $price['amount'], $price['currency_code'], $product),
            '1' => '1 KG  ' . commerce_currency_format(1 * $price['amount'], $price['currency_code'], $product)
        );
        $piece_array  = array(
            '1' => '1 stuks ' . commerce_currency_format(1 * $price['amount'], $price['currency_code'], $product),
            '2' => '2 stuks ' . commerce_currency_format(2 * $price['amount'], $price['currency_code'], $product),
            '3' => '3 stuks ' . commerce_currency_format(3 * $price['amount'], $price['currency_code'], $product),
            '4' => '4 stuks ' . commerce_currency_format(4 * $price['amount'], $price['currency_code'], $product),
            '5' => '5 stuks ' . commerce_currency_format(5 * $price['amount'], $price['currency_code'], $product),
            '6' => '6 stuks ' . commerce_currency_format(6 * $price['amount'], $price['currency_code'], $product),
            '7' => '7 stuks ' . commerce_currency_format(7 * $price['amount'], $price['currency_code'], $product),
            '8' => '8 stuks ' . commerce_currency_format(8 * $price['amount'], $price['currency_code'], $product),
            '9' => '9 stuks ' . commerce_currency_format(9 * $price['amount'], $price['currency_code'], $product),
            '10' => '10 stuks ' . commerce_currency_format(10 * $price['amount'], $price['currency_code'], $product)
        );


        if ($field_price_type == 'Prijs per kilo') {
            $select = $weight_array;
        }
        if ($field_price_type == 'Prijs per stuk') {
            $select = $piece_array;
        }

        $form['quantity']['#type']    = 'select';
        $form['quantity']['#options'] = $select;
        $form['quantity']['#size']    = 1;
        $form['quantity']['#default_value'] = 0.1;
    }
} 

// Cart page
if (strpos($form_id, 'views_form_commerce_cart_form_default') === 0) 
{
    //dpm($form_id);
    //dpm($form);
    //dpm($form_state);

    if (isset($form['edit_quantity'])) {            
        foreach ($form['edit_quantity'] as $key => $quantity_field) {               
            if (is_array($quantity_field)) {                    
                // query the DB for each line item in order to get the product id
                $entity_type = 'commerce_line_item';
                $query = new EntityFieldQuery();
                $query->entityCondition('entity_type', $entity_type, '=')->propertyCondition('line_item_id', $quantity_field['#line_item_id'], '=');
                $result = $query->execute();

                if (!empty($result[$entity_type])) {
                    // load the full line item information
                    $line_item = entity_load($entity_type, array_keys($result[$entity_type]));

                    // get the options array if a select box is necessary
                    $product = $line_item[$quantity_field['#line_item_id']]->commerce_product['und'][0]['product_id'];   
                    $prd_wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('commerce_product', $product);
                    $field_price_type = $prd_wrapper->field_prijs_type->value();

                    $weight_array = array(
                        '0.10' => '100 gram ' ,
                        '0.20' => '200 gram ' ,
                        '0.30' => '300 gram ' ,
                        '0.40' => '400 gram ' ,
                        '0.50' => '500 gram ' ,
                        '0.60' => '600 gram ' ,
                        '0.70' => '700 gram ' ,
                        '0.80' => '800 gram ' ,
                        '0.90' => '900 gram ' ,
                        '1.00' => '1 KG  '
                    );
                    $piece_array  = array(
                        '1.00' => '1 stuks ' ,
                        '2.00' => '2 stuks ' ,
                        '3.00' => '3 stuks ' ,
                        '4.00' => '4 stuks ' ,
                        '5.00' => '5 stuks ' ,
                        '6.00' => '6 stuks ' ,
                        '7.00' => '7 stuks ' ,
                        '8.00' => '8 stuks ' ,
                        '9.00' => '9 stuks ' ,
                        '10.00' => '10 stuks ' 
                    );  

                    if ($field_price_type == 'Prijs per kilo') {
                        $select = $weight_array;
                    }
                    if ($field_price_type == 'Prijs per stuk') {
                        $select = $piece_array;
                    }
                    //dpm($line_item);
                    //dpm($line_item[$quantity_field['#line_item_id']]->quantity);

                    $form['edit_quantity'][$key]['#type']           = 'select';
                    $form['edit_quantity'][$key]['#options']        = $select;
                    $form['edit_quantity'][$key]['#size']           = 1;
                    $form['edit_quantity'][$key]['#default_value']  = $line_item[$quantity_field['#line_item_id']]->quantity;
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

---

Answer (score 0):

Streamlining the above answer. To switch quantity textbox to be a select field...

```
function THEME_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  switch ($form_id){
    case 'views_form_commerce_cart_form_default':
      $select = array('1' => '1 ','2' => '2 ','3' => '3 ','4' => '4 ','5' => '5 ','6' => '6 ','7' => '7 ','8' => '8 ','9' => '9 ');

      foreach ($form['edit_quantity'] as $key => $quantity_field) {
        $form['edit_quantity'][$key]['#type']           = 'select';
        $form['edit_quantity'][$key]['#options']        = $select;
        $form['edit_quantity'][$key]['#size']           = 1;
        $form['edit_quantity'][$key]['#default_value']  =    $line_item[$quantity_field['#line_item_id']]->quantity;
      }
      break;
  }
}
```